# tracking misspelled words from applespell.service

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to record any words that are detected as being misspelled on mac osx.

I see that `AppleSpell.service` is the apple system spellcheck server so ideally I'd like a way to listen to that service and record when a misspelled word is detected.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/nudfn8p2y0yp95g/Screenshot%202017-01-18%2020.10.11.png?dl=0  However I can't find a source for this file or documentation for any api for it.

I've also looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/Tasks/CreatingSpellServer.html but it doesn't document any way to subscribe to a server/service.

Is this possible?  Is there any way to listen to a service or more precisely a way to listen for and record words that are detected as being misspelled on mac os x.

If the only way to do this is to build a new spell checking service are there any good guides on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Hi Daniel, is what you want is checking for misspelled words in your Cocoa app (such as in your app NSTextField)? Or you want to get notifications when the Apple Spell service marks a word as misspelled?

Comment: Hi @BaoNguyen I'm looking for the latter.  The ability to be notified when the apple spell service marks a word as misspelled.